# Unchecked cast from Object, generic class and wildcards

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

Here is my code:

```
public class ArrayTaskList<E> {
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        ArrayTaskList<E> other = (ArrayTaskList<E>) obj;
        if (!Arrays.equals(db, other.db))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

And compiler says:

> Type safety: Unchecked cast from object to arraytasklist

I understand, that it's jst an warning, but if i try this code, there are no warnings:

```
ArrayTaskList<?> other = (ArrayTaskList<?>) obj;
```

Is it more convenient solution?

Comment: In your case solution that you have is far enough, as Arrays.sort() accepts Objects or primitive types so you don't need to know exact type <E>

Comment: The warning is because the original cast gives you false type safety. A cast like `(Foo) bar` means "check if `bar` is of type `Foo`". Unfortunately, it's not possible to tell whether an object is of type `ArrayTaskList<E>` - because of type erasure, we only know it's an `ArrayTaskList<?>`. That is, it can contain objects of any type, and we don't know what type of object you can add to it. The correct solution is using your second code, and downcast the indicitual elements as necessary. (Which it shouldn't be, because you can call `Object.equals()` on them.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is that the raw type object is not typesafe while the unbounded wildcard gives you type safety.

For example with a raw type you can have code like this:

```
List list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add(42); // integer
list.add(true); // boolean
list.add(whateverYouWant); // whatever you want
```

while this code:

```
List<?> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
list2.add(42);
list2.add(true);
```

will cause a compiler error.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following implementation instead:

```java
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return obj instanceof ArrayTaskList && obj.hashCode() == hashCode();
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Arrays.hashCode(db);
}
```

That way, there's no *unchecked cast* problem anymore ;)

But please note that due to type erasure,

```java
new ArrayTaskList<String>().equals(new ArrayTaskList<Integer>())
```

will return `true` if both have the same `db` array, even if one used `String` while the other one `Integer` as class parameter.

Answer (score 0):

When execution reaches that line, you know that `obj` is an instance of `ArrayTaskList`.
However, you don't know whether it is an `ArrayTaskList<Integer>` or `ArrayTaskList<String>` etc.

Thus, the cast generates a warning (you could try to cast a `ArrayTaskList<Integer>` to `ArrayTaskList<String>`).

However, you don't need the type information here, so using `ArrayTaskList<?>` would indeed be the better solution here.

**EDIT**:

I had some misconception here, since even using type's boundary would cause the warning.
As @svz pointed out, `ArrayTaskList<?>` won't add any assumptions and just enables type checking.

The compiler trusts you that the cast to `ArrayTaskList` is ok, while the warning is generated because you make the assumption of `obj` also having the type `E`. The compiler can't check that and thus issues the warning. With `<?>` or `<? extends XYZ>` the compiler will ignore the type but will raise errors if any method that might fail is invoked.

Consider the following example:

Your class is `ArrayTaskList<E extends Number>` and thus you'd cast to `ArrayTaskList<Number>` or `ArrayTaskList<E>` (where `E` could be `Long` for example).

In that case the compiler doesn't know whether `E` is of type `Number`, `Long` etc. and thus warns you, since `obj` could be a `ArrayTaskList<Double>` and casting that to `ArrayTaskList<Number>` would allow you to add Longs to a list of Doubles (ouch).

Hence the compiler warns you of that cast.

Casting to `ArrayTaskList<?>` would tell the compiler to ignore the type but raise errors if you called `other.add(...)`, preventing you from accidential inconstencies.

**Edit 2:**

I still have some misconception here (I'll think more about this), but so far, here's a way to cast without a warning and still use any upper bound that `E` might provide:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
  ...      
  return equals_((ArrayTaskList<?>)obj);
}

protected boolean equals_(ArrayTaskList<? extends Number> other)
{      
  if (!Arrays.equals(db, other.db))
        return false;
  return true;
}
```

Comment: What if `<E>` is declared as `<E extends MyCommonInterface>`?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza What if it is? You can't really cast it to `List<MyCommonInterface>` because then you could add a different subclass of `E` to the list which would be wrong. Or maybe I'm not sure where you're going with that question.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza you're right, that would still generate the warning.

Comment: @millimoose I mean that probably later in that code you need to go through the elements of the list, but since it is a `<?>` you couldn't use any of the methods in `MyCommonInterface>` if declared as `<E extends MyCommonInterface>` (and assuming there's no `ClassCastException`).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Okay but the OP's code has an `Object obj` parameter. At that point the only type-safe thing  to do is: `for (Object it : (List<?>) obj) { MyCommonInterface mci = (MyCommonInterface) it; ... }` - that way the `ClassCastException` will be thrown on a line with an actual cast on it.

Comment: @millimoose agreed. I think I just get used to add a `@SuppressWarnings(value = "unchecked")` when encountering these cases.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Oh, that's what I do myself when I *know* the other object has the right type but don't feel like adding boilerplate and design contortions to get the last ounce of type safety. (And when I'm not leaking the collection anywhere it could get corrupted.) I'm just saying that said last ounce is indeed not there in that case.

Comment: @millimoose yes, I use it when I *know* the other object type either. In cases like OP's specific problem where the list should be generic there's no need to use this.

Answer (score 0):

You could also pass in the `ArrayTaskList` constructor an inscance of `Class<E> clazz` and then the cast can be done `clazz.cast(...)`:

```
public class ArrayTaskList<E> {
    Class<ArrayTaskList<E>> clazz;

    public ArrayTaskList(Class<ArrayTaskList<E>> c) {
        clazz = c;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        ArrayTaskList<E> other = clazz.cast(obj);
        if (!Arrays.equals(db, other.db))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```